# Serve multiple Django applications from one server

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Good morning. I have a dedicated ubuntu server behind my company's firewall. It is using Django, Gunicorn, and Nginx to serve an Intranet application to employees. The original app responds to the URL [server_name]/[original_application_name]. I want to serve additional apps from this server. I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial as I did when setting up the original app.

I can run Gunicorn and serve the app, I have created a second systemd service file that appears steady (copied from the original app with paths changed - service runs), same for a new 'sites-available' file in Nginx (copied from original and modified), new .sock file exists, binding appears successful. However, I have yet to hit on the right configuration combination between settings.py [allowed_hosts], [new_app].service, and nginx etc.

The original app is running and when I try a URL related to the new app it gives an error saying it cannot find the request in the url.py of the original app. The new app would be used by the IT dept. Ideally, the new URL would be something like: it.[server_name]/[new_application_name].

I have looked through other cases with this problem but most use Apache or are on a public hosting site. I have seen [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-deploy-multiple-django-apps-as-subdomains-using-nginx-and-gunicorn) but it requires a "socket file". My original app is not using a socket file. I was hoping to do this without interfering with the original app. Is a "socket file" required? How can I configure this to serve both apps? Never having done this, what will the new URL be? The URL for the admin site in both apps is 'admin/', how can I accommodate this? Thanks!

I combined into one file as you suggested and I am almost there! I have original site responding at [server_name]/inventory and new site responding at [server_name]/assets. Great! My only problem is the admin page. In both apps the admin site is called admin! So, [server_name]/admin brings up the original site. How can I get to the new admin page?

Comment: You said the .sock file exists. That *is* the socket file. But we cannot help you without seeing your nginx configuration.

Comment: I added the 2 nginx/sites-available files.

Comment: I don't understand why you have two separate nginx files though. If you want them both serving on the same domain then you need a single file with different locations.

Comment: I think it was https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-deploy-multiple-django-apps-as-subdomains-using-nginx-and-gunicorn that led me to having two nginx files. Easily fixed, I will combine them as you suggest.

Comment: Almost there! How can I resolve the admin page part? Thank you!

Comment: You can just give it a different path in urls.py.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195153/discussion-between-tuffgong-and-daniel-roseman).